# Programatically turn Tomcat on and off for Spring Boot Rest

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-rest

While my Spring Boot Rest application is already running, I want to be able to turn the Rest functionality on and off at will programatically **without** having to restart the application.

How do I go about doing so?

EDIT: When I say turn off Rest Functionality I literally mean that Tomcat stops listening on the port. And it starts listening on the port again when it's turned on.

Comment: How do you want to turn it off/on? Through wich gate? How is that?

Comment: Two questions come to mind.  Do you want to turn it off for all REST end points or pick and chose?  When turned OFF, what HTTP response should be returned?

Comment: @tmarwen somewhere in my code, for example 12AM everyday it stops listening to any calls on the REST port and 6AM everyday it starts listening again on that port

Comment: @JoseMartinez Good questions, I have edited above. I want the application to stop listening on the port completely so as if nothing was ever listening on that port.

Comment: Would you consider using CRON to turn it off?  The problem is that Tomcat is the Servlet container that it is running in.  So turning OFF Tomcat is akin to turning the whole application off.

Comment: @JoseMartinez I have one other use case, where for example my Rest app checks to see if the other microservices in the ecosystem are running, and if not then I want it to close the port so the load balancer stops sending requests to it as any requests sent to it will most likely not be successful as it sends them downstream to these other microservices that are offline.

Comment: Oh ok.  Well one thign we have done in the past for similar scenarios is to have a keepAlive API that the loadbalancer would call.  A microservice can  programatically respond with an error (or DOWN) when that /keepAlive endpoint is called.  Keep alive endpoint is a common feature of modern load balancers.  Do you know if the load balanncers in your network support that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151733/discussion-between-molten-ice-and-jose-martinez).

Comment: @JoseMartinez I think the proprietary load balancer my company uses isn't as smart as that, it can only check if the port is open or not :) But thanks for your input!

Comment: You could have the loadbalancers point to a reverse proxy like Nginx or Apache HTTP server.  Those servers could proxy all requests to your Tomcat microservice.  A peice of code in your microservice could control the stopping and starting of the local proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two possible solutions:

1. Close the port on the machine by creating a schedueled task that is responsible of opening and closing the port on specific times
2. In Spring terms, what you want to do boils down to a configuration change. SpringBoot provides a standard way to refresh configuration changes without having to restart your application. This is achieved by [refreshable beans](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/docs/1.0.x/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope). What you can do is override the default Tomcat bean by a custom bean that is refreshable. Then you can create a task (through a CI, schedueled script ...) that will update the configuration (you can provide config as Env variables) and refresh the beans of the application.

The first solution is much easier. The second approach needs some more development inside your application.